# Cloudflare blocking AJAX file upload FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax, cloudflare

I'm having a problem with CloudFlare blocking my AJAX call to upload an image using   the method below.  I know it's something in CloudFlare, because my other site which is not routed through CloudFlare works fine.

```
// Perform AJAX check on Image to ensure dimensions meet our minimum requirement
var theForm = $('#upload_image_form')[0];
var theFormData = new FormData(theForm);
// We need to know if this is a Home page banner or Page banner
if ($('#PAGE_ID').val() == '') {
    banner_type = 'home';
} else {
    banner_type = 'page';
}
theFormData.append('banner_type',banner_type);
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_banner_image_check.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: theFormData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
         console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Any idea what I need to do to make this work?  Basically, the image file gets corrupted and the PHP script on the other end which takes the file and processes it using imagecreatefrom[extension] dies and throws an error that the image file is invalid.

Do I need to disable something specific in CloudFlare for this to work, or can I add something to the request to allow it to pass through without being seen as potentially malicious?

I already looped over the formData var and echo'd out to the console to make sure it was setting correctly, which it is.

Comment: The corrupted data problem doesn't necessarily sound like a hosting issue. If it was due to your hosting it's more likely the request would be blocked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I've narrowed it down to something in CloudFlare that is doing it.  This process was working exactly as is a few weeks ago, so something has changed on their end that is now interfering with this process.

Comment: I'd suggest putting in a support request to them then (assuming you haven't already) as your JS logic is fine. It may be worth you adding the PHP logic too for someone more familiar with that to check as wll.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it’s the size of your file. Cloudflare limits you to <= 99MB for the free plan. I am currently working on this problem too. I think we need to send the photo from the Ajax form to the backend in chunks.